# How to store list<Object> to hive db

Tags: flutter, hive

I have a question about hive db. is it possible to store List data type? That's what Hive's documentation says: Generic type parameters like Box are unsupported due to Dart limitations. But i need to store chat with room id and messages.

Lets imagine like that

[image]

that is, I need to store 2 different data types into the hive object, List (for message) and int (for id). is it possible? if you have any other ideas please share with me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved  this logic worked for me

```
final data = ChatStorage(
  roomId: widget.room!.id,
  chat: state.messages,
);

if (chatBox.isEmpty)
      chatBox.put(widget.room!.id, data);
    else {
      List<int>? roomIds = [];
      bool available = false;
      for (var chat in chatBox.values) {
        roomIds.add(chat.roomId!);
      }
      if (!roomIds.contains(widget.room!.id)) available = true;

      if (available) chatBox.put(widget.room!.id, data);
   }
}
```

I think this method will help if someone is facing such a problem